# Visual Studio 2008 Error "copying contents file" in MFC project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc

I inherited a legacy MFC project that was upgraded from Visual Studio 6.

the project compiles in debug mode, but when I put it in release mode, I had an error where the help file could not be compiled.

I removed the file that was causing this problem, but now some command line is trying to copy a legacy file from the help folder to the bin folder.

Is there a way to set the properties so that nothing is copied?  I am relatively new to C++.

Comment: All custom build steps are in .vcproj [Project Files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2208a1f2(v=vs.90).aspx). .vcproj files are XML and thus human-readable. There is no setting you can enable so that nothing is copied. Build systems are way more complex than you appear to think.

Comment: Thanks. I really only want to stop the release build from trying to create the .hlp file, and stop it from trying to create and copy a .cnt file in the hlp folder.

Comment: Thanks Ilnspectable.  I was able to manually delete the setting in the .vcproj file, and now the project correctly compiles in release mode.